# Saving photo to image in Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, imageview, swift4.2

I am having a problem displaying the photo I just took or chose to the image view.

Below is a pic of the imagview on the left and the licencePhoto button on right.

[image: imageview and button]

When I click on Take Photo, it allows me to take a pic or select from my library, as the code shows:

```
@IBAction func seclectOrTakePhoto(_ sender: Any) {

    pickerController.delegate = self
    pickerController.allowsEditing = true

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add a Picture", message: "Choose From", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.pickerController.sourceType = .camera
        self.present(self.pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    let photosLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photos Library", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(self.pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    let savedPhotosAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Saved Photos Album", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.pickerController.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
        self.present(self.pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil)

    alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
    alertController.addAction(photosLibraryAction)
    alertController.addAction(savedPhotosAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)


    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

But, it does not display the photo to the licensePhoto image and in Firebase, it is uploading the pic I have displayed in the image view as below and not the one I just took with phone.

How can I achieve this?

### Edited

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    self.licensePhoto.image = image
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


    // any time the photo changes, check the button status
    updateSignupButtonStatus()


}
```

Comment: You should include your implementation of `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` so we can see how you are saving the image and what you are loading into the imageView.

Comment: see EDIT ... I added imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingImage:)

Comment: I finally figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and looking through tutorials, I finally got something to work:

```
@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    licensePhoto.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    licensePhoto.image = chosenImage
    pickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```